# Lift map when the bottom sheet is first shown (collapsed)

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I need the map to be lifted when the bottom sheet first appears (collapsed state). That is, the "Google" logo should not be hidden behind the sheet. But the map view stay the same when the bottom sheet is dragged from there to the top. That is basically how Google Map works. Is there a way to tell the map view to lift itself when the bottom sheet is shown in collapsed state?

MainActivity

```
package com.loser.bsproblem

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback
{
    var mBottomSheet:BottomSheetBehavior<NestedScrollView>?= null;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mBottomSheet = BottomSheetBehavior.from(homer);
        mBottomSheet?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN;

        val mapFragment = this.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapView) as SupportMapFragment;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap?)
    {
        var marker = MarkerOptions()
        marker.position(LatLng(51.501518, -0.141847));
        marker.title("My house");
        p0?.addMarker(marker);
        p0?.setOnMarkerClickListener {
            if(mBottomSheet?.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)
            {
                mBottomSheet!!.peekHeight = 400;
                mBottomSheet!!.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED;
            }
            else
            {
                mBottomSheet?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
            }
            true;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.loser.bsproblem.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        map:cameraTargetLat="51.501518"
        map:cameraTargetLng="-0.141847"
        map:cameraZoom="16"
        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/homer"
        android:background="#EEEEFF"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="This is bottom sheet"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]